# Filter a custom attribute in Order Grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order, filter, custom-attributes, order-grid

I added new attribute and new column to **Order Grid** :

`[vendor]\[module]\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="sales_repesentative" class="[vendor]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sales Representative</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`[vendor]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status.php`

```
<?php

namespace [vendor]\[module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);

    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {    
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);        
                $dealer = $order->getSalesRepresentative();
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $dealer;  
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

But when I want to **Filter** or **Sort** the grid base on new column, I get this error:
[image]